# Transform $m-$simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $n-m$ components are $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given are $m+1$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m< n$. These $m+1$ points define a non-degenerated $m-$simplex. How to rotate (and shift) the points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that we can write the simplex with $m$ instead of $n$ coordinates, i.e. the last $n-m$ components of all coordinates are zero? The Euclidean distances between the points shall not be changed. Reflections are allowed.

Could Principal Component Analysis be used or is this method reserved for statistical data? There should be a simpler way of finding an orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix that rotates the points. Is additional shifting needed or rotation sufficient?

*Example*

Given are points $\bf{x}$,$\bf{y}$,$\bf{z}$ that form a $2$-simplex (triangle) in $\mathbb{R}^4$. We have $m=2,n=4$, and because $n-m=2$ we can set two components to $0$.
How to rotate (and shift) the points $\bf{x}$=$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, $\bf{y}$=$(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$, $\bf{z}$=$(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ so that they can be written like $\bf{x'}$=$(x'_1,x'_2,0,0)$, $\bf{y'}$=$(y'_1,y'_2,0,0)$, $\bf{z'}$=$(z'_1,z'_2,0,0)$?

Comment: There are perhaps some linguistic issues here, but have you tried QR factorization?

Comment: Please define "relative position".  Ignoring reflections for the moment, I took it to mean pairwise euclidean distance. The $Q$ in QR factorization allows for this.  If $Q \in O_n(\mathbb R) -SO_n(\mathbb R)$ (i.e a. reflections) then there is an easy adjustment.  Note: $QR$ factorization is much simpler than PCA despite your initial (now deleted) comment/assertion that there must be a method much simpler than QR factorization.

Comment: @user8675309 I encourage you to write this up as an answer, which should also let you go into enough detail to address the confusion. (I think - I'm guessing - that you were misunderstood to mean "replace the $m$ points by an orthonormal basis for their subspace" which certainly doesn't do *either* of the things we want.)

Comment: (One more detail, though, is that the $m$ points span an $(m-1)$-dimensional *affine* subspace, and a translation is also necessary. It is straightforward to deal with this by translating an arbitrary one of the points to $\mathbf 0$.)

Comment: When you say  "span a plane" you probably mean "the affine span is a plane".  So any solution should probably begin by translating the configuration so that one of the points is the origin. Then you can rotate to make the last coordinates $0$.

Comment: @granularbastard I almost agree with you. I would agree completely  if you had explicitly said "affine span" instead of "span" since the latter usually means "linear span".

Comment: @MishaLavrov it's unfortunate since OP has edited this many times, but if you check the time stamps my comment about QR factorization was necessarily in relation to the original post 2 days ago that said "These m points span a subspace in  $\mathbb R^{m-1}$" which was one of the linguistic issues I alluded to since obviously points don't span vector spaces, vectors do.  If an affine space is intended then translation becomes relevant.  But the underlying idea of computing the desired rotation as $Q^T$ from appropriate QR factorization stands.

Comment: @user8675309 I agree with everything you've said! I think that whatever the question means, the issue of affine span vs. linear span is a minor one and the use of QR factorization is the main point - which is why I encourage you to write it up as an answer instead of leaving it as a comment :)

Comment: @user8675309 So far I thought that a point and a vector have the same meaning, except that a vector has also a direction from the origin. The direction plays no role for the problem, only the endpoint of the vector is of interest. Maybe there are different meanings in different contexts and you could give a reference,

Comment: In your example, if the three points are linearly independent, no nonsingular linear transformation can map them into the two-dimensional linear subspace $\{p \in \mathbb R^4: p_3 = p_4 = 0\}$.  You'd need an affine transformation (so translation in addition to rotation).

Comment: @granularbastard -- points don't have much to do with vector spaces (vectors do).  However points make a lot more sense in the context of affine spaces-- or as now for determining simplices,  It is overkill but if you want to get *granular* then the first section of chapter 2 in Gallier's *Geometric Methods* is quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $m+1$ affinely independent points
$\big\{\mathbf v_0, \mathbf v_1, \dots,\mathbf v_{m}\big\}$ and in particular are interested in taking convex combinations of these, a subset of affine combinations.

First apply a translation:
Define $\mathbf a_k:=\mathbf v_k-\mathbf v_0$
We are now working in a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ generated by
$\big\{\mathbf a_1 \dots,\mathbf a_{m}\big\}$
These are linearly independent vectors.

Now collect these in matrix
$A:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} \mathbf a_1 & \mathbf a_2 &\cdots & \mathbf a_{m}\end{array}\bigg]$
where $A$ is injective.  Using "full" QR factorization
$A=QR$
$Q\in O_n(\mathbb R)$ and $R$ is "upper triangular" but not square (in fact it is tall and skinny).  This means that $r_{i,i}\neq 0$ in all cases and $r_{i,j}=0$ for $i\gt j$.  Then

$Q^{-1}A=Q^{T}A$  gives the desired result of coordinate vectors that are zero in each component after the $m$th.

---

**To recap:** we first apply a translation $\mathbf v_k\mapsto \mathbf v_k -\mathbf v_0$, then a rotation $(\mathbf v_k -\mathbf v_0)\mapsto Q^T(\mathbf v_k -\mathbf v_0)$, both of which are rigid motions.

**As an aside**, if you let $E$ be the type 3 elementary matrix with a $-1$ in the bottom right corner then
$A=QR=QE^2R=(QE)(ER)=(QE)R$ and checking the determinant, it must be the case that $Q\in \mathbb SO_n(\mathbb R)$ or $(QE)\in \mathbb SO_n(\mathbb R)$. I.e. you can use always assume you used a bona fide rotation if you like.

Comment: Could you explain why $Q^{-1}A=Q^{T}A$ delivers the desired result?

Comment: We know $\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} \mathbf r_1 & \mathbf r_2 &\cdots & \mathbf r_{m}\end{array}\bigg]=R = Q^TA=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} Q^T\mathbf a_1 & Q^T\mathbf a_2 &\cdots & Q^T\mathbf a_{m}\end{array}\bigg]$ and each column of $R$ has all zeros below the $m$th component.  So for $j\in \big\{1,2,\dots, m\big\}$ the combined mapping described under "to recap" is $\mathbf v_j\mapsto \mathbf r_j$ and of course $\mathbf v_0\mapsto \mathbf 0$ which trivially meets your requirement of having the last $n-m$ components all zero.

Comment: Better to move this in the answer.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @user8675309 Is it possible to get the result without previous shifting?

Comment: In some cases yes, in some cases no.  You will need to check on specifics related to "linear independence".  To make this concrete, consider the simplest case where $m+1=n$ and the 'points', when viewed as vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are linearly independent, then no it is (hopefully obviously) impossible but if they're linearly dependent then yes it's possible.  When talking about affine spaces, translation is very natural and linear independence really is an unrelated concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think the principle component analysis is not what you want. It's for reducing statistical data, you seem to have a different problem.

What you want can be achieved by successively applying rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the planes spanned by the unit axes, like this one that rotates by $\alpha$ in the $e_3$-$e_4$-plane:

$$
\mathbf{Q}_{34}(\alpha)=\left[\begin{matrix} 
1      & 0      &            0 &            0 & 0 ... \\
0      & 1      &            0 &            0 & 0 ... \\
0      & 0      & \cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} & 0 ... \\
0      & 0      & \sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} & 0 ... \\
0      & 0      &            0 &            0 & 1 ... \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots       &       \vdots & \vdots 
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Let's assume you have three points in $\mathbb{R}^6$ labeled $\mathbf{P}_{1,2,3}$. Then you can transform these like so

$$
\mathbf{P}_1'  = \mathbf{Q}_{36}(\alpha) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{46}(\beta) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{56}(\gamma) \cdot \mathbf{P}_1 \\
\mathbf{P}_2'  = \mathbf{Q}_{36}(\alpha) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{46}(\beta) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{56}(\gamma) \cdot \mathbf{P}_2 \\
\mathbf{P}_3'  = \mathbf{Q}_{36}(\alpha) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{46}(\beta) \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{56}(\gamma) \cdot \mathbf{P}_3
$$

Then you have three angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to make the sixth' components of $\mathbf{P}_{1,2,3}'$ zero. Then you do

$$
\mathbf{P}_1''  = \mathbf{Q}_{25}(\alpha') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{35}(\beta') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{45}(\gamma') \cdot \mathbf{P}_1' \\
\mathbf{P}_2''  = \mathbf{Q}_{25}(\alpha') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{35}(\beta') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{45}(\gamma') \cdot \mathbf{P}_2' \\
\mathbf{P}_3''  = \mathbf{Q}_{25}(\alpha') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{35}(\beta') \cdot \mathbf{Q}_{45}(\gamma') \cdot \mathbf{P}_3'
$$

and use $\alpha',\beta',\gamma'$ to make the fifth components of $\mathbf{P}_{1,2,3}''$ vanish, and so on.

Put into a Mathematica notebook the algorithm looks like this:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
p1 = {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/Sqrt[3], -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), 0, 1/2};
p2 = {1/2, 0, -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/Sqrt[3], -(1/(2 Sqrt[3]))};
p3 = {1/(2 Sqrt[3]), -(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/(2 Sqrt[3]), -(1/2), 0, 1/2};
p4 = {-(1/2), 0, 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/Sqrt[3], -(1/(2 Sqrt[3]))};
(* P1 is the new origin, so we have to deal only with three points *)
(* t is the list of location vectors that we want to rotate such that *)
(* the trailing components are zero *)
t = {p2 - p1, p3 - p1, p4 - p1};

n = Length[p1];
m = Length[t]; 
alphas = Array[alpha, m];
For[ss = n, ss >= m + 1, ss--,
    Print[ss];
    Print[MatrixForm[t]];
    (* create rotation matrices *)
    Rs = Table[mat = IdentityMatrix[n];
               mat[[ss - i, ss - i]] = Cos[alphas[[i]]];
               mat[[ss, ss]] = Cos[alphas[[i]]];
               mat[[ss - i, ss]] = Sin[alphas[[i]]];
               mat[[ss, ss - i]] = -Sin[alphas[[i]]];
               mat, {i, 1, m}];
    (* apply rotations *)
    tmp = Rs[[1]] . Transpose[t];
    For[ii = 2, ii <= m, ii++, tmp = Rs[[ii]] . tmp];
    (* solve for the unknown angles with random initial values to break symmetries *)
    erg = FindRoot[tmp[[ss]], Table[{alphas[[ii]], Random[]}, {ii, 1, m}]];
    (* update the list of points*)
    t = Transpose[tmp /. erg];
]
Print[MatrixForm[t]]
Graphics3D[Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, t[[1, 1 ;; 3]], t[[2, 1 ;; 3]], t[[3, 1 ;; 3]]}]]
```

Comment: Could this be performed in a single step by a single rotation matrix where the angles  are expressed as functions of the original coordinates? Shifting is necessary? I only see shifting in the code.

Comment: Yes, as explained in the other answer with the Q-Matrix. Note that user8675309 also shifts $\mathbf{v}_0$ to the origin.